# Specified cast is not valid - Object to long

Tags: c#, registry

I'm working on some code that writes a DateTime value to the Windows registry and then retrieves it.

**Code**

```
RegistryKey subKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\" + Project.Properties.Resources.PRODUCT_NAME, true);

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
subKey.SetValue("TrialEndDate", dt.ToBinary());

DateTime dt2 = DateTime.FromBinary((long)subKey.GetValue("TrialEndDate"));
```

The last line throws the following exception:
`Specified cast is not valid`

The FromBinary method expects a `long` parameter so I'm attempting to cast the object returned from GetValue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [SubKey.SetValue(string, object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k23f0345(v=vs.110).aspx), the value is stored as a string unless it is a 32-bit integer. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kk9bxk9(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Numeric types other than 32-bit integers are stored as strings by this method overload. Enumeration elements are stored as strings containing the element names.

This present a problem, because `DateTime.ToBinary` produces a 64-bit integer. So it will be converted to a string for storage. When you retrieve the value you are `cast`ing instead of `Convert`ing, so it'll fail.

If you want to store the date as a binary number, you can fix this by using [the overload of SetValue that lets you specify the type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k23f0345(v=vs.110).aspx). For example:

```
subKey.SetValue(trialEndDate, dt.ToBinary(), RegistryValueKind.QWord);
```

This will store the binary value as a 64-bit integer and allow you to retrieve it as the same.

You could also choose to store the DateTime as a string (which might be more readable to someone editing the registry) and parse it using `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`. This is probably how I would do it:

```
const string FORMAT = ""yyyyMMddHHmmss";
RegistryKey subKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\" + Project.Properties.Resources.PRODUCT_NAME, true);
var dt = DateTime.Now;
subKey.SetValue("TrialEndDate", dt.String(FORMAT), RegistryValueKind.String);
var storedValue = subKey.GetValue("TrialEndDate") as string;
var dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(storedValue, FORMAT);
```

Comment: I don't really understand why this Reflection method is not able to cast and set whatever Type you forced if it's compatible. Example it completely makes sense if I say `property.SetValue(obj, property.PropertyType.ToDefault(value));` where `ToDefault(this Type type, object value)` and **Type = System.Byte** passing `object value = 2`. I think this should be improved in coming versions of .NET

Comment: @YeinCM-Qva Maybe I am confused, but I don't see any use of Reflection in the question or the answer. Can you clarify?

Comment: I know it's a little bit confused. I was talking about the `SetValue` method from Reflection .Net library which has that overloading you stated in your answer for certain specific types with the `RegistryValueKind` parameter but I think the framework or language or the JIT compiler should have improvements to address this casting issues that have been hanging around for a long time.

Comment: @YeinCM-Qva I am not sure your comment makes sense in this context. The registery's `SetValue` method doesn't cast or convert any C# objects; it simply determines the format to be used for serialization into a registry key. In the context of Reflection, no conversion is ever needed-- you need to cast, which is because c# is a type-safe language. That is a feature, not a flaw. Perhaps I am not understanding what you mean by "casting issues."